# Umlauts in search?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, special-characters

I tried to find an answer of mine which has a word with an umlaut in its body, it didn't quite work out though.

Search string [`user:546730 übermensch`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:546730%20%C3%BCbermensch) gives these results:

[image]

The search was supposed to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887681/how-to-insert-into-a-column-in-data-grid/5888400#5888400).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'll support other (non `A-Z` & `a-z`) Unicode characters in search starting with the next build so your *exact* search works.  If you want to search *before* we push that (sometime later today) then use quotes like this:

[`user:546730 "übermensch"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:546730%20%22%C3%BCbermensch%22)