# ² (squared) not a valid search or URL character

Tags: bug, search, unicode, auto-linking

The character `²` is not a valid search character. On *[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)*, one common term is [I²C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C), sometimes (correctly) spelled as I²C (IIC or I-squared-C). A search for `I²C` does not throw an error, nor does it return anything with `I²C`. Instead it results in questions and answers including `IC`, an unrelated term. And the automatic URL recognition does not work when `²` is in the URL.

For example **[https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203076/i²c-bit-banging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203076/i%C2%B2c-bit-banging)**

Notice how it hyperlinks I²C bit banging to `https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203076/i`, while dropping `²c-bit-banging`?

Sometime between writing this bug report and 2022, the automatic URL recognition no longer tries to fix the URL. After editing the question, the broken renaming went away, so just the link shows. The rest still doesn't work properly.

Notably, `²` is valid in a URL, so it will bring up the correct question if copied and pasted, or hyperlinked, but not in the search or URL parsing.

Can this be fixed by the code review team? This is a valid Unicode utf-8 character `Superscript 2` hex `0x00B2`

**If anything, can a search for, and results for, `²` be mapped to `2`?**

<sub>*This is not a duplicate of that question, because **this does not work, while that was fixed**. So this is a new issue.*</sub>

Comment: Related: [Search and Unicode characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104295/search-and-unicode-characters) – Unicode characters should be valid search terms.

Comment: Re *"dropping ²c-bit-banging"*: Is that still the case? What browser or mobile app (incl. version) was this tested on? Is it about rendering on the Stack Exchange pages? And/or what URL is redirected to in the browser?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum As of the OP’s yesterday edit, it says that it is *not* the case any longer. You just removed the “Edit:” label that made that clear. Perhaps the whole discussion of URLs should be removed, now that it is no longer relevant.

Comment: @emil no it is still broken, in a different way

Comment: Is it? As the post is written now, it says that the URL handling is fixed, only searching is broken. If this is not what you mean, please rewrite it clearly. Please remove all the distracting bits about what was broken before and how it changed. Just state clearly what is broken *now*.